# "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" - I already did

Tags: bug, comments

[image: Screenshot]

No need to tell me to do something I've already done.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106992/dont-add-would-you-like-to-automatically-move-this-discussion-to-chat-when (applies to all sites)

Comment: It's more annoying when it says "Move to chat..." and the OP doesn't have enough rep to actually use chat. Surely that's a simple check that can be used when deciding if that message should be displayed.

Comment: @Tanner. Not that simple. There are three chat systems: SO, MetaSE, and SE. The first two of those are each associated with only one site, the third with all the rest of the sites. So your rep on SE chat is your aggregate rep across all SE sites excluding SO and MetaSE. Calculating that is a pain.